# Java Plugin unable to save file

Tags: java, plugins, jar

I am making a plugin for open source project Tv-browser. For it I have to make a jar file with specific naming conventions as documented by authors and have to save that jar file in plugins directory of Tv-browser installation directory.

Every thing is working just fine when making my plugin. I can receive data from Tv-browser and make my Frame visible, can handle events from my frame.

But when it comes to saving a file on system, all failed. I need to save a file on the system.

I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a util.io.IOUtilities class in the open tv-browser api that can save data to files on the local disk.